# wp_before_admin_bar_render action not working in back office

Tags: wp-admin, admin-bar

This is working great in the front site wp admin bar:

```
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'customize_admin_bar');

function customize_admin_bar() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        if ( !is_admin()) {
          $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('edit-profile');
          //$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('user-info');    
          $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');
          $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-media');
          $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-tvr_booking');
          $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-vp_orbitslides'); 
          $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('orbitslider_settings');
          //$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('site-name');
          //$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('dashboard');
          /*$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
            'id' => 'custom-account',
            'parent' => 'my-account',
            'title' => __( 'Mi cuenta'),
            'href' => '/pedidos/products-page/your-account/'
            ) );*/
        }

    }
}
```

but not in the wp-admin menubar, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, but you have a `!is_admin()` condition. That will prevent the bulk of that code from running on the back end. Remove that and the code should work on both front and back.

Comment: THANKS! used !current_user_can('administrator') instead, cause I want the actual admin to be able to see everything